# Sharepoint 2010 - wpresources for Bin / web Application Deployment

Tags: deployment, visual-studio, web-application, resource-files

In SharePoint 2010 , using visual studio 2010 :
i have bin / web application deployment.
i want to add  java script file under Virtual Directories\/wpresources//

I cannot use the Resources mapped folder as it points to {SharePoint}/Resources ie 14 hive/ Resources folder.

Can i know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Real Answer, first version of this answer is an alternative solution, see comments for clarification*

Set the Deployment Type to Class Resource for the module. [See here for an example](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/09/sharepoint-visual-studio-2010-adding-classresources-web-part/).

Alternative Answer:

You could have javascript files live in the LAYOUTS folder if possible, they'll be the most accessible there.

Add a mapped folder for LAYOUTS, add in a folder for the name of your project if you want (if it doesn't already do so) and then access it via /_layouts/YourProjectName/file.js

Comment: As per the requirement i want the JavaScript files to be in Virtual Directories - Resources folder only.

Comment: So, to clarify, you need to add class resources in visual studio 2010? If so, here's how to set the deployment type of a module in VS2010 to ClassResource: http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/09/sharepoint-visual-studio-2010-adding-classresources-web-part/

Comment: Worked !!!!! Awesome post 
Thanks a lot for the quick reply